# VMware Fusion is not opening (close after a second from launch)

Tags: vmware, catalina

I am experiencing an issue with VMware Fusion on macOS Catalina (latest version). When I click on the VMware button, it launches for a second and then closes.

Before this happened, I was playing with the VMware settings (I removed SATA1). I tried to uninstall it from my laptop and install again but the issue still remains.

Any help?

Comment: Just to clarify your question: the VMware (app) preferences don't contain a setting for SATA devices, only VMware machines do (besides other devices like virtual network interfaces, cameras etc. What did you do exactly?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "When I click on the VMware button"? Are you having an issue with the VMware Fusion app itself or one of the Virtual Machines you've created? What version of VMware Fusion do you have installed? If it's not at least 11.5.0, then I'd try using it.

Comment: yes I have an issue with the app itself, it is not opening. I have VMware fusion 11

Comment: @0xx7 Please be more specific: there is a wide range of different VMware Fusion 11 dot (dot) versions (11.0.0-11.5.0). Only 11.5.0 is fully compatible with Catalina.

Comment: the exact version is 11.5. Last time before this happen, I was trying to fix an issue, I exported a VM and try to launch it, but it launches with black screen. Then this happened, now the application itself doesn't open at all.

Comment: I run the VMware console in the content folder and I got this error https://ibb.co/JCB216y